# Checking equality of integers: O(1) in C but O(log n) in Python 3?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, python, c

Consider these equivalent functions in C and Python 3. Most devs would immediately claim both are $O(1)$.

```py
def is_equal(a: int, b: int) -> bool:
  return a == b
```

```c
int is_equal(int a, int b) {
  return a == b;
}
```

But consider what is happening under the surface. Integers are just binary strings and, to determine equality, both languages will compare the strings bit-by-bit. In either case this scan is $O(b)$ where $b$ is the number of bits. Since integers have a constant size in bits in C, this is simply $O(1)$.

*EDIT: C doesn't compare bit-by-bit [see this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/127944/123062)*

In Python 3 however, integers do *not* have fixed size and the scan remains $O(b)$ for the number of bits in the input, or $O(\log a)$ where $a$ is the value of the input in base 10.

So if you're analyzing code in Python, any time you compare two integers, you are embarking on a  surprisingly complex journey of $O(\log n)$ with respect to the base 10 value of either number.

For me this raises several questions:

1. Is this correct? I haven't seen anyone else claim that Python compares ints in log time.
2. In the context of conducting an interview, should you notice or care if a candidate calls this $O(1)$?
3. Should you notice or care about this distinction in the real world?

*EDIT: It is easily verified (and intuitive) that Python cannot compare arbitrarily large ints in constant time. So a better way to ask question 1 above might be "What (if any) is the justification for calling this operation $O(1)$? Because it's pragmatic? Conventional? Implied by the RAM model?*

Comment: "I haven't seen anyone else claim that Python compares ints in log time" -- here is an example of Tim Peters (inventor of Python's TimSort, among many other contributions to Python), saying exactly that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061819/13005. This being the CS site, possibly we should say it's linear, anyway, since we should conventionally be analysing complexity in terms of the size in bits of the input, not the magnitude of the value the input represents :-)

Comment: In every interview setting I experienced, the input was bounded and calling this O(1) is correct. Also, I would take more issue with someone who couldn't explain the behavioural difference between the two program (arbitrary precision vs 64 bit) than someone assuming O(1) for the python one, since the latter is in almost all contexts legitimate under business constraints - even for crypto code, although the constants involved can be quite large, they are still bounded. Not posting this as an answer, since it doesn't quite fit the theoretical nature of CS-exchange.

Comment: The fact that it is more expensive to work with big ints is one of the reasons that numpy can provide a speed boost over base Python. The problem has also been discussed as part of the Python 2 to Python 3 transition. See [Why is Python 2.7 faster than 3.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23426756/4996248)

Comment: This appears to be an issue of when to define computational complexity in terms of the number of inputs vs the bit-complexity (or log of the magnitude) of the input.  Does this article help?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_of_computational_complexity

Comment: You mention base 10 twice. Why do you think base 10 comes into play? You still talk about bits, so I'm very confused about what you think.

Comment: @JiK By that I just mean that _n_ refers to the actual value of the input, not its length in bits. E.g. for _5 == 5_, _n_ is just 5.

Comment: Your C version is missing a `;` in the C version.  https://godbolt.org/z/PLwDNs has a working version, showing how it compiles to a single compare operation on real CPUs (handling all bits in parallel, not looping over a bit-string).  I suggested [an edit](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/80462) that fixed the C as well as clarifying that ISO C doesn't say how operations are implemented internally; that's up to individual implementations that e.g. compiler to asm for real CPUs.  But you rejected it.  At least fix your C so it compiles.

Comment: unless you're using a dialect older than C99, the equivalent C function would be ```_Bool is_equal(int a, int b) {return a == b;}
```

Comment: In python, if you are comparing numbers of identical datatypes (e.g. integers), you can use `a is b` which *could* be faster.

Comment: @WorldSEnder WIth bounded input, everything is $O(1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: There is a CS convention of describing this type of operation as $O(1)$ which happens to break down in extreme cases for Python. These cases are *extremely* rare, so to break with the convention of $O(1)$ has negative utility. This kind of pragmatism is normal in big $O$.

There are a lot of very good responses to this question and I encourage you to read them. But I don't think any one of them fully answer my questions. So here's a synthesis.

> Is this correct? I haven't seen anyone else claim that Python compares ints in log time.

This is surprisingly nuanced. It is **true** that Python compares very large ints in $O(\log n)$ runtime. But is it *correct* to describe this operation as $O(\log n)$?

Ultimately I'm most persuaded by this take from @TomvanderZanden:

> If you said the C or Python version was $O(1)$ any interviewer should be perfectly happy. If you said it (the Python version) was $O(\log n)$ they would probably still be happy, but think you are a rather pedantic person who doesn't follow normal conventions.

and

> If I was an interviewer, I would care whether you know the real-world limitations of what you are doing and know what theoretical concerns matter when and that you bring them up if and only if appropriate.

However I'm not accepting that as the answer because I think the first paragraph is currently misleading (happy to change).

Ultimately this argument is pragmatic. By the strict definition of big $O$ Python int comparison is still verifiably $O(\log n)$. But it is not useful to treat it that way, so you shouldn't. I would add that to be strict about big $O$ is to miss the point of big $O$ analysis.

Comment: Are there other examples like this where we ignore some nuance and call a technically-more-complex operation O(1)? I assume there must be many. Inserting to a hash table doesn't count because we still teach that this is O(n) worst case.

Comment: One example of this: looking up a string of length k in a hash table is technically O(k) even in the best case, because every char of k must be read. But strings are generally assumed to be "reasonably small" enough that this is commonly ignored.

Answer (score 25):

> Integers are just binary strings and, to determine equality, both languages will compare the strings bit-by-bit.

Not quite. C `int`s are machine-word-sized and compared with a single machine instruction; Python `int`s are represented in base $2^{30}$ (see e.g. https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/) and compared digit-by-digit in that base. So the relevant base of the logarithm is $2^{30}$.

If *at least one* of numbers can be bounded by $2^{30d}$ for *any* fixed $d$, the comparison is $O(1)$ (because the number of digits is compared first), and if they can't, other operations are likely of much more concern than equality comparison. So in practice I'd say it's very unlikely to matter and if it does you'll know (and would be using not `int`s but something like the [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org) in C as well).

Comment: If you compare the same numbers as the C program does, then you know the numbers are < 2^64, so d <= 3. In practice, most numbers that are compared are less than 2^30 so d = 1. But if you need to compare integers around 10^10000, then C doesn't do that out of the box, and you need to write C code running in O (log n).

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about saying this explicitly and don't remember why I didn't.

Comment: Special case for the first paragraph: 8-bit machines like AVR (8-bit RISC microcontroller) need 2 registers to hold an `int` (C requires `int` to be at least 16 bits).  This means compare is a fixed sequence of sub / sub-with-carry.  (Actually `cp`/`cpc` which is like sub but doesn't store the integer result, only flags).  https://godbolt.org/z/pAy8sc.  That doesn't spoil your point, and your phrasing is a useful simplification of the thorny details of C portability.

Comment: C doesn't say anything about how many machine instructions are used to compare ints.

Answer (score 16):

Complexity is defined relative to a computation model. P and NP, for example, are defined in terms of Turing machines.

For comparison, consider the word RAM model. In this model, memory is divided into words, words can be accessed in constant time, and the size of the problem can be represented using $O(1)$ words.

So, for example, when analysing a comparison-based sort operation, we assume that the number of elements $n$ can be stored in $O(1)$ words, so it takes constant time to read or write a number between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: This is outside my existing knowledge, but quick research suggests that the RAM model isn't what is conventionally assumed when just using big O notation. Since I can observe that Python does *not* compare integers in constant time, I'm not sure why we'd assume that here. If we make "conventional" assumptions (Turing model?) how does that change your answer?

Comment: @jtschoonhoven The RAM model is *far* more common.

Comment: It seems conventional that this does _not_ apply to string comparisons, which I hear cited as O(n). So integers are assumed to fit the word size and strings aren't?

Comment: @jtschoonhoven : Yes.  An arbitrary length string of characters is not assumed to fit in a (prespecified constant number of) word(s) while an integer type (necessarily fixed width) is assumed to fit in a constant number of words.

Comment: @EricTowers That makes sense and explains why it is conventional to speak of integer comparisons as constant time. In Python however, integers are ultimately stored in non-fixed width arrays, very much like strings. If the question was asked "what is the runtime to check equality of two unbounded arrays of 32 bit elements" it would obviously not be constant. Why does it change if we later learn that those arrays represent integers? I understand the utility of treating it (1) in most cases, but if we want to get pedantic about it isn't it still (n)?

Comment: @jtschoonhoven : Python integers are **not** always represented as variable length arrays of words.  And, in "almost all" programming languages (and models of typed computation) integral types are fixed width.

Python is bizarre in having an integral type that silently switches representation between global constant objects  ($O(1)$ compare), a fixed-width integral type (in the usual sense of the word) ($O(1)$ compare), and a variable length array of words ($O(\log n)$ compare).  Why would you expect general language to apply to a bizarre example?

Comment: I don't think it's a bizarre example, it's the primary language I work in and I want to describe its behavior accurately.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven : You *cannot* describe its behaviour accurately.  Its behaviour is strongly dependent on the implementation.  The $O(1)$ shortcut to compare signs or zero via struct member `ob_size` is not standardized among implementations.  The range $[-5,256]$ of global constant objects is not standardized and an implementation may use a larger range.  The representation as a hardware compatible (possibly multiprecision)  integral type is guaranteed for the interval $[-2^{30},2^{30}]$ but an implementation is permitted to use a larger range.  Implementations are free to find more shortcuts.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven : To expand on that first shortcut.  If two integers' $ob_size$ are not equal, then their equality is false.  Thus, "nearly all" pairs of representable integers can compare equality in $O(1)$ time even if they are both represented as arrays of words.  The array of words need only be consulted if the two integers have the same sign and length.  Some implementations take this shortcut and some don't.

Comment: @EricTowers In big $O$ we're concerned with bounding the worst case, so shortcuts are not typically relevant unless they apply in all cases. As $n$ approaches infinity, in *all* common implementations the behavior will be $O(\log n)$. If we knew the range of possible inputs then it would be $O(1)$ by definition, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven : You seem to be immensely resistant to the point:  The behaviour of this operation is implementation dependent.  The instant this is the case, it is $O(1)$ because all implementations run on bounded machines.  If you want to talk about an abstract machine, then you permit unbounded implementations.  You will have to specify that abstract machine.  Python does not do so as can be seen by the wide range of implementation freedom.

Answer (score 9):

> Is this correct? I haven't seen anyone else claim that Python compares ints in log time.

No (and a little yes). Consider the following thought-provoking (but not really true) claim: A computer can only have a finite amount of memory (bounded by the number of atoms in the universe), so the Python version is also $O(1)$.

The problem is that we are trying to make a statement about asymptotics (pertaining to what happens at infinity) about a finite state machine (a computer). When we are analyzing the complexity of code, we don't actually analyze the code itself as it would run on a computer, we are analyzing some idealized model of the code.

Suppose I asked you to analyze a sorting algorithm written in C. You might state it uses ints to index the array, so it could only ever sort an array of size up to $2^{31}-1$. Yet, when we analyze such a piece of code, we pretend that it could handle arbitrarily large arrays. Clearly, we are not saying C integer comparison is $O(1)$ *because* it can only handle 32-bit numbers.

> In the context of conducting an interview, should you notice or care if a candidate calls this O(1)?

Usually, not. Suppose I am conducting an interview and ask you to write a C or python computer program that counts the number of female employees appearing in the employee database.

It would be *incredibly* pedantic if I complained your C program was incorrect because it could only count up to $2^{31}-1$.

We generally assume that numbers are small enough that they can fit within one word/integer. We assume addition (or any other number operation) can be done in $O(1)$, because it would be very annoying to have to write $O(\log n)$ everywhere and it would just make everything unreadable even though $\log n$ is so small it doesn't really matter anyways.

If you said the C or Python version was $O(1)$ any interviewer should be perfectly happy. If you said it (the Python version) was $O(\log n)$ they would probably still be happy, but think you are a rather pedantic person who doesn't follow normal conventions.

> Should you notice or care about this distinction in the real world?

Yes! It starts to matter when numbers get so large the assumption they are small is violated. Let's say you are interviewing for Google and they asked you to compute the number of search queries done by female users in the past year. The interviewer would be quite justified to complain if you wrote a C program using ints.

You could switch to using longs and still be justified in calling it $O(1)$, and similarly, calling the Python version $O(1)$ is also justified. The $O(1)$ v.s. $O(\log n)$ thing only starts to matter when the numbers get very long. For instance, if your task is to write a program that computes digits of $\pi$ or some similar task. If you wrote a Python program for this task and didn't mention the peculiarities of complexity when asked, the interviewer would care.

If I was an interviewer, I would care whether you know the real-world limitations of what you are doing and know what theoretical concerns matter when and that you bring them up if and only if appropriate.

**When should you care?**

So far, I've been a bit vague about "large" and "small" numbers. In the commonly used RAM model, you're allowed to assume that integer operations can be done in $O(1)$ on numbers that have at most $O(\log n)$ bits (where $n$ is the length of the input). The justification for this assumption is that if we have an input of length $n$, the pointers/indices in our programming language should be long enough to be able to address the entire input space. So, in the RAM model, if the input is binary number of $n$ (binary) digits, the complexity of checking equality is $O(\frac{n}{\log n})$ since we can check the equality of one group of $O(\log n)$ bits in one $O(1)$ operation.

Comment: _"A computer can only have a finite amount of memory (bounded by the number of atoms in the universe), so the phyton version is also O(1)."_ - By that reasoning, you can reduce _any_ algorithm to O(1) complexity. The number of nodes in a graph is bounded in a similar way, so TSP? O(1). It's an utterly useless argument. If you want to argue that in this case O(log n) doesn't really come into play in practical scenarios, then argue that. I'd agree. But don't pretend O(log n) = O(1) because the number of atoms in the universe is bounded.

Comment: @marcelm I am not saying (which I should perhaps have made clearer, I can see it comes across badly now) we should treat everything as $O(1)$ or that it is sensible to say that Python addition is $O(1)$. It is meant as a though-provoking introduction to the answer to get the reader thinking about applying asymptotic analysis to real-world computers. No real-world implementation of C nor Python can handle arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: I like this answer a lot but after the first edit I still don't feel convinced by the opening thought experiment and I'm hesitant to accept it as the answer. Comparing two strings is commonly described as $O(n)$ for the length of the shorter string: if Python integers behave similarly, why would it be different? Other than that it would be pedantic (which is true). I think what you're getting at is that it is *correct* to describe this operation as $O(\log n)$ but almost never *useful*.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven: Perhaps you're thinking of implicit-length strings where finding the length also costs O(n) work, which you can do while comparing (like C `strcmp` that works on 0-terminated C strings).  Explict-length strings like C++ `std::string` can early-out by comparing the lengths in O(1) time because the length is stored in a known place.  To avoid overread of the shorter array, you have to compare the lengths anyway; if you know the lengths are different it makes *no* sense to actually scan the arrays for equality, unless you're actually checking that A is a prefix of or equal to B.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not familiar with C++ but big $O$ bounds worst-case performance, i.e. the case where strings are the same length.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven: big O is an *upper bound* on the complexity class, which isn't the same thing as worst case, e.g. QuickSort is usually described as an $O(n \log n)$ sort.  But yes, string / BigInt compare is O(n) for equal lengths (in which case there's only one unique `n`), or implicit-length in which case `n` = length of shorter.  ([In units of "limbs" for BigInt stuff in general](//mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1414); 30 bit chunks for Python). Python BigIntegers are like this in the general case of huge ones of similar size, but that's not how most problems use integers in Python.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven: But in the common case of normal problems, e.g. using huge amounts of small integers as problem size scales up, each individual integer still only costs O(1) to operate on.  If scaling up `n` for the problem you were talking about did involve larger and larger integers, then yes you'd need to account for that whether you wrote it in Python and let the interpreter do it, or whether you wrote it in C and the BigInt stuff was a more visible part of the source code.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden note that even assuming the universe is infinite and has infinite amount of electrons/matter to store our infinite matter, the RAM model breaks down since at that scale speed of light starts to matter, i.e. you can't access "the farthest" bit in constant time (as far as modern physics is concerned).

Answer (score 6):

Although this may seem like a trivial point, your first sentence is incorrect. *The functions are not equivalent*. To make them equivalent, the C function should use GMP (or similar) to implement arbitary-precision arithmetic. Now, the reason this observation is not trivial, is that the extent to which it's reasonable to say that the two are equivalent, is precisely the extent to which it's reasonable to say that the Python code is constant-time! That is, if we're going to ignore that Python's integers are bignums, we can (and should) consistently treat them as fixed size.

Analogously, consider the C function `int is_equal(char a, char b) { return a == b; }` and the Python function `def is_equal(a: str, b: str) -> bool: return a == b`. It is more obvious now that the functions are not equivalent, but the reason for that is exactly the same as the reason yours aren't. We just expect to see massive strings in Python all the time, but don't really expect massive ints even though of course we know they are possible. So, most of the time we ignore the fact that Python's integers are big, and we analyse as if they are fixed-size. In the rare cases where we care about the timings of bignum operations, you can use the "real" complexities. And, of course, also use GMP in your C code.

All this is to say: although you didn't realise it, you already know the answer to your restated version of your question at the end, and the answer is, "the same justification by which you described those functions as equivalent". Python is unusual in not having a fixed-size integer type (well, not one that people commonly use: it's possible to write one of course, and there's one in `numpy`). But as a matter of pragmatism, we don't want this to prevent us doing the "usual" complexity analysis of algorithms that crunch integers, and getting the "usual" answers. It is rarely necessary to provide the caveat that if we pass it a couple of 10GB integers that are nearly equal, it might take a little while to compare them.

In some cases you could formalise this (if you really need to) by saying that you're restricting your analysis to small integers. Then, you might consider complexity of some algorithm in terms of the size of some array of integers, treating all arithmetic operations as O(1). If you're considering algorithms which really are linear or worse in the magnitude of the integer, then you could formalise it by saying you're going to ignore the log-factor, since all you really care about is whether the complexity is closer to linear or quadratic, because O(n log n) is as good as linear for your purposes. Almost all the time, though, you don't need to formalise the complexity of algorithms *in Python*. If you've reached the point of specifying a programming language, you're not really doing abstract computer science any more ;-)

> In the context of conducting an interview, should you notice or care
> if a candidate calls this $O(1)$?

Depends on interview for what, I suppose, but as a software professional, working primarily in Python for the last 10 years, I would not ask that in an interview. If I asked a question which had the complexity of integer comparison hidden inside it (like, I dunno, "what's the complexity of this sort algorithm?"), then I'd accept an answer which ignored the whole issue. I'd also accept one which addressed it. I do think it is worth understanding and computing complexity as part of practical programming, I just don't consider it that important *for programming* to be very careful about formally stating that you're talking about reasonable-sized integers.

I would also never ask a question in which I want the candidate to offer the information that Python integers are arbitrary-precision, when it's not obviously relevant to the the question for some reason to do with the data involved. If the question implies that the numbers involved can go higher than 2<sup>64</sup> then in a C interview I'd want the candidate to notice that this is a problem they need to deal with, and in a Python interview I'd want the candidate to know that it isn't, but I wouldn't expect them to go out of their way to state it. There isn't time in an interview to state every little fact that makes something a non-problem.

If I wanted to check understanding of complexity in an interview, then mostly likely I'd start by asking for some code for some problem where there's a really straightforward "naive" solution with poor complexity, and at least one less straightforward solution with decent complexity using well-known techniques. If the candidate offers the naive solution, then you can ask what the complexity is and how they'd modify the code to improve it. If the candidate offers a better solution then you can describe the naive solution, point out how few lines of code it is, and ask what's wrong with it (perhaps by asking, "if you were reviewing someone's code and they gave you this, what would you say about it"?). For most practical purposes all you care about is whether they can tell the difference between linear, quadratic, and worse-than-quadratic. O(n log n) also appears, but mainly because of sorting or data structures where you're talking about complexity in terms of the number of comparisons. The cost of each comparison is usually considered irrelevant, because the algorithm designer usually has no control over it (it's provided by the user of the algorithm or data structure).

In the astonishingly unlikely event that I was the interviewer for a position as a CS academic covering arbitrary-precision arithmetic, then certainly I would want candidates to know the complexities of various algorithms for various operations, and indeed to know the state of the art for the non-trivial ones.

Comment: Right, that the functions are not *actually* equivalent is the point. This question is somewhat contentions because there is a convention of considering integer comparisons as $O(1)$ which breaks down in extreme cases that are specific to Python. My question is ultimately about whether this matters in practice, and I agree with your assessment that (usually) it doesn't.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven: and in particular that the *way* they're inequivalent is that the Python one is "more powerful", but almost all the time we aren't using that power (and if pressed we could formally prove we aren't). Therefore it's mildly misleading to make too much of the fact that in some sense we "should" have to pay for that power in complexity. We're not really paying for the power of the Python function, we're at most paying for our laziness in not properly formalising some practical restrictions on the domain of the function.

Comment: You're missing a `;` in your C function, like the question.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven: in fact it's just occurred to me that `int` in Python can be subclassed. Therefore, even if the type hints are enforced (which typically in Python they aren't), the Python function is even less equivalent to the C function than I've already outlined. `==` does not necessarily call the `int` equality operation. It is a call to arbitrary user code, and we have no way to analyse what its time complexity might be. So there's another way to formalise, which is to refuse to speak in those terms and merely say the complexity of the code is `O(1)` comparisons.

Comment: ... once we have some information about what gets passed into the function, maybe then we can talk time complexity in terms of cycle count or what-have-you :-)

Comment: And, coincidentally, I have just been writing some code this morning which uses `fraction.Fraction`, and ends up doing arithmetic on integers which are non-trivially large: 800 decimal digits, although that was by way of a soak test. Sure, I could speed it up using `float` instead, but then I'd have to actually think about whether the stuff I'm doing is numerically stable or not, and whether underflow could lead to a division-by-zero failure. It probably is fine, but the runtime has not yet reached slow enough that I care to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*: Based on the comments, I've decided to preface my answer with a correction.  I used big-O notation to talk about an operation.  However, this notation is really applied to a complexity class, which gets defined by a *metric* on that operation.  For example, it may be "the number of additions required in the worst case."  or it might be "the number of seconds required in the average case."  Both can use big-Oh notation to describe a *bound* on the series ([big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm) can be used on any sequence, not just runtime metrics).

Technically the meaning of O(1) or O(log n) has no meaning unless you specify the metric.  However, colloquially speaking, when computer scientists talk about a sorting algorithm being O(n log n) without specifying the metric, they are implicitly talking about the worst case behavior in "number of instructions".  This is the meaning I used in my answer below.  Many commenters pointed out that this was not formally correct.  However, from your question's wording, it appears you are using this implied metric, and I used it below.  Purists are free to substitute in the above clarification in any sentences which use big-O notation without reference to a metric.

---

> Is this correct? I haven't seen anyone else claim that Python compares ints in log time.
> Python does indeed have an arbitrary precision integer format.  However, we have to make a fair comparison here.  If we consider the subset of integers on the bound of $[0,2^{64}]$, we find that the Python operation is constant time.

What you are seeing is one of the limits as to measuring computational complexity using big-oh notation.  It describes what happens as n approaches infinity, but does not necessarily do a good job of comparing the behavior for smaller numbers.  We see this famously in [matrix multiplication algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm).  There are some algorithms which are more efficient in a big-oh sense, but are actually slower in practice until you get to gargantuan matrices.

> In the context of conducting an interview, should you notice or care if a candidate calls this O(1)?

Depends on what you are hiring them for.  For the vast majority of jobs, calling it O(1) should be fine.  Indeed, it is how we tend to teach it in school.  If you wanted to turn it into a useful opportunity to learn about your candidate, you might ask them why they think addition is constant time (to which the answer is that the model they used to determine big-oh assumed it... which is a valid answer)

If you are hiring someone to look for things like exploits in your code, you may want to push futher.  A bignum produced by your own code is one thing, but is the user allowed to input the number of their own choosing?  If so, they may be able to create timing attacks and DOSs using the fact that this addition can be terribly slow.  Detecting this risk might be part of their job.

> Should you notice or care about this distinction in the real world?

Practically speaking: no.  Not until you acutally run into it, and fix the issue in debug.  Python does a *lot* of things that are "generally safe" and are very efficient.  This is why it has taken over as one of the most popular languages in the world.

For an equivalent situation: how fast is `x.y` in Python?  We think of it as O(1), but there's actually a hash lookup there.  That hash lookup uses a known probing mechanism, and the resulting lookup is actually O(n).  You'll never see this in normal code.  But in code where an adversary gets to fill your dictionary with their own content, they can intentionally craft keys that collide in this way.

Comment: My understanding is that big O _supposedly_ always refers to worst-case performance unless otherwise specified. But I hear hash table lookups frequently referred to as O(1) without specifying we mean average performance. This is probably pragmatic, but the inconsistency in the industry has made this confusing for me.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven Big-Oh is "worst-case," but practically speaking it only speaks of the worst case as "n" approaches infinity.  It's an artifact of how there's a constant-multiple hidden in the definition.  For any finite "n", every algorithm is O(1), as you can always select a constant large enough.  And yes, the mislabeling of hash tables as O(1) stems from the fact that O(n) scares people, but practically speaking hash tables have amazing performance.  I will tell people "you can treat it like O(1), as long as you don't have an intelligent adversary choosing your keys"

Comment: @jtschoonhoven big-O isn't "best-case", "worst-case", *or* "average-case". It's "bounded above by", contrast with big-omega, which is "bounded below by" and big-theta, which is "bounded above and below by"

Comment: "If we consider the subset of integers on the bound of [0,264], we find that the Python operation is constant time." well yes, but my point is that Python ints _aren't_ bounded in this way. Not trying to make a fair comparison between Python and C, I'm curious about how we should talk about Python ints in general.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven : "Python ints aren't bounded in this way"...  It depends.  As [implemented by CPython](https://rushter.com/blog/python-integer-implementation/), ints in that range (in fact, in a very much larger range), are treated as 32-bit int types.  If you get serious about profiling, you will see this change in behaviour as arguments pass around $2^{30}$.  In fact, there are two additional optimizations, $0$ is indicated in the data structure, not in the array of words, and integers in the range $[-5,256]$ are global constant objects, not arrays of words.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven The answer is really "it depends."  Technically, the operation is indeed O(log n).  However, what it is showing here is that Big-oh is not really telling you the story you need to really understand what is going on.  Its the wrong tool for the job in 99% of these integer cases, only being the important way to think about things in  a handful of unbounded cases (such as doing RSA cryptography).  Big-oh is really overrated in a lot of these situations.

Comment: And there isn't technically anything "wrong" about saying its O(1), as long as your model is measuring the number of additions.  Just like how in C++, we don't consider the feed-forward nature of addition in the hardware which actually takes O(log n) time, but we never treat it as such (beacuse even if we finish quickly, we still wait for the end of a cycle before propagating the bits to the next stage of the pipeline)

Comment: Furthermore, it's not that unusual to be in a situation where O(log n) can reasonably be modelled as O(1) with a big constant factor. Because the fundamental observation that (in most practical cases) log n < 64 is kind of smug but it's nevertheless often non-trivial. A factor of 64 might even be less than the performance difference between different optimisation levels. Whereas the observation that (in most practical cases) n < 2^64 *is* a trivial observation, because a constant factor that large is no practical help whatever.

Comment: @Caleth: right, so it addresses the worst-case to the extent that any upper bound necessarily must be a bound on the worst case (well, "worst" assuming that "slow" is "bad"). Naturally you can also talk about O/Theta/Omega bounds on the average case, if you want to ignore sparse killer inputs, or amortise occasional slower performance in a series of operations.

Comment: @CortAmmon: Please, don't say Big-O is worst-case when it has utterly nothing to do with that. It is **extremely common** to see worst-case and expected time bounds, and most of them are given as Big-O bounds. For example a hash-table with $n$ hashes and a uniformly random hash-function takes O(1) **expected time** for each search or insertion or deletion if you store no more than $n$ objects in it at any one time. Quick-sort with random pivot takes O(n·log n) **expected time**. And so on...

Comment: @CortAmmon It appears you mistakenly edited *my answer* instead of your own while you apparently meant to edit your own. I've rolled back the change (to my answer). Feel free to add your edit to your own answer.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Thank you for catching that!  Sorry for the accidental vandalism!

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered a text that treated "regular" integer operations as anything besides constant time, with the implicit assumption that the size had some reasonable finite upper bound (for example 64 bits). Perhaps it would be more accurate to state the assumption, but to a CS audience, I think it is implicit.

Doing so would introduce a lot of complexity into discussions of essentially unrelated topics. Bigint implementations typically are not implemented bit by bit, but in base-(machine word size), so that O(b) > O(1) problem only kicks in for fabulously large numbers.

Personally while interviewing someone, I might appreciate the rigor and breadth of knowledge associated with knowing Python integers were arbitrary length, but anything beyond stating the assumption that all math is O(1) would feel extremely pedantic. If the analysis started getting too far off-topic with arithmetic, and wasted time, I would consider this a bad candidate.

Comment: Agree and my question isn't meant to be pedantic. I'm still getting a sense of how strict one is expected to be with big $O$ and when you're allowed to make reasonable, implicit assumptions like this.

Comment: @jtschoonhoven Asking here is definitely *not* pedantic! Thinking about how numbers are stored is also generally a good idea, even if not in big-O. I think the CLRS Algorithms book actually specifically addresses assumptions, but I can't seem to find my copy. I will dig around for it and see if I can find a reference for you.